# Validate username as alphanumeric with underscores

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

On my registration page I need to validate the usernames as alphanumeric only, but also with optional underscores. I've come up with this:

```
function validate_alphanumeric_underscore($str) 
{
    return preg_match('/^\w+$/',$str);
}
```

Which seems to work okay, but I'm not a regex expert! Does anyone spot any problem?

Comment: this will allow hyphens and I think periods as well

Comment: I think whitespace as well might be valid with \w

Comment: For PRE, \w  matches a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_"), according to the official Perl documentation: http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlre.html

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The actual [matched characters of `\w` depend on the locale](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php) that is being used:

> A "word" character is any letter or digit or the underscore character, that is, any character which can be part of a Perl "***word***". The definition of letters and digits is controlled by PCRE's character tables, and may vary if locale-specific matching is taking place. For example, in the "fr" (French) locale, some character codes greater than 128 are used for accented letters, and these are matched by \w.

So you should better explicitly specify what characters you want to allow:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9_]+$/
```

This allows just alphanumeric characters and the underscore.

And if you want to allow underscore only as concatenation character and want to force that the username must start with a alphabet character:

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/
```

Comment: Why? \w is exactly alphanumeric characters and underscore.

Comment: Actually, \w is alphanumeric characters and underscore according to the active locale, so depending on the circumstances, it might match characters like 'ü' or 'ö'.

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Gumbo's extra options are useful so I'll go with that. Cheers!

Comment: Well, I think this one will prevent usernames ended up having `_` in the end: `/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*[^_]$/`. How do you think?

Comment: @Mahdi That’s not necessary as the string must end with either `[A-Za-z]` (single character) or `[A-Za-z0-9]` (either from `[A-Za-z0-9]*` or, when containing a `_`, from `[A-Za-z0-9]+`). In opposite to that, your pattern will allow any last character other than `_`.

Comment: @Gumbo oh yeah, you're right! I gotta go change my validation code now! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: How can i limit it to 32 characters ?

Answer (score 20):

Here's a custom function to validate the string by using the [PHP ctype_alnum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) in conjunction with an array of allowed chars:

```
<?php

$str = "";
function validate_username($str) {

  // each array entry is an special char allowed
  // besides the ones from ctype_alnum
  $allowed = array(".", "-", "_");

  if ( ctype_alnum( str_replace($allowed, '', $str ) ) ) {
    return $str;
  } else {
    $str = "Invalid Username";
    return $str;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Generally speaking, I like avoiding regular expressions where I can. For this sort of validation this seems less error prone and is easier to understand (developer only needs to know php, doesn't need to know regex syntax). The solution is unique to php but that's what I'm looking for. Thx.

Answer (score 10):

try

```
function validate_alphanumeric_underscore($str) 
{
    return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/',$str);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks fine to me. Note that you make no requirement for the placement of the underscore, so "username_" and "___username" would both pass.

Comment: Could you tell me how to set the limit to one underscore between letters?

Answer (score 1):

I would take gumbo's secondary regex, to only allow underscore as concatenation, but add a + after the _ so a user can be like "special__username", just a minor tweak.

`/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_+[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/`

Answer (score 0):

Your own solution is perfectly fine.

`preg_match` uses Perl-like regular expressions, in which the character class `\w` defined to match exactly what you need:

> `\w` - Match a "word" character (alphanumeric plus "_")

([source](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions))