# PHP regular expression for alphanumeric and hypen input

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to validate input depending on whether it only contains a combination of letters, numbers and hyphens (where a hyphen is not repeated twice-in-a-row and does not begins/ends the string)?

Thanks to [Validate username as alphanumeric with underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330693/php-validate-username-as-alphanumeric-with-underscores)

I know that the following validates a string based on alphanumeric input with underscores, would it be possible to alter this?

```
function validate_alphanumeric_underscore($str) 
{
    return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/',$str);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done quite easily with a single regular expression:

```
/^([a-z0-9]+-)*[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

This meets all your criteria:

- No double hyphens
- No beginning/ending hyphens
- Works when strlen == 1

Matches:

- [a](http://dev.meagar.net/preg?preg=%2F%5E%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B-%29%2A%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%24%2Fi&query=a&replace=)
- [a-a](http://dev.meagar.net/preg?preg=%2F%5E%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B-%29%2A%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%24%2Fi&query=a-a&replace=)
- [a-a-a](http://dev.meagar.net/preg?preg=%2F%5E%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B-%29%2A%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%24%2Fi&query=a-a-a&replace=)

Doesn't match:

- [-](http://dev.meagar.net/preg?preg=%2F%5E%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B-%29%2A%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%24%2Fi&query=-&replace=)
- [a-](http://dev.meagar.net/preg?preg=%2F%5E%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B-%29%2A%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%24%2Fi&query=a-&replace=)
- [-a](http://dev.meagar.net/preg?preg=%2F%5E%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B-%29%2A%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%24%2Fi&query=-a&replace=)
- [a--a](http://dev.meagar.net/preg?preg=%2F%5E%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B-%29%2A%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%24%2Fi&query=a--a&replace=)
- [a-a--a](http://dev.meagar.net/preg?preg=%2F%5E%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B-%29%2A%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%24%2Fi&query=a-a--a&replace=)

Play with it [here](http://dev.meagar.net/preg?preg=%2F%5E%28%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B-%29%2A%5Ba-z0-9%5D%2B%24%2Fi&query=ab-c-defg-hij-k).

Comment: **You win.** (15-char padding)

Comment: +1. The other answers may work, but they're all much more complicated than they need to be.  I do wonder, though, why so many people choose to put the optional part first.  `/^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$/i` seems clearer to me, and it's a little more efficient, too.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a minimum of 2 characters:

This will validate the general format (not starting or ending with a `-`).

```
/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]$/i
```

Then add a simple check for double hyphens using `strpos` (if it's false, there is no `--` in the string, so we want to return `true`.  Otherwise, we want to return `false`, so that's why the `false ===` is in there):

```
false === strpos($string, '--');
```

So, you could do it as:

```
function validateAlphaNumericUnderscore($string) {
    if (0 < preg_match('/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]$/i', $string)) {
        return false === strpos($string, '--');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now, I'm sure there's a way to do it in a single regex (without needing the additional `strpos`), but I'm blanking on that now.  This is a simple regex, and a simple second string comparison (non regex based).

Hopefully this suits your needs...

**Edit:** In fact, you could make this more efficient by checking for the `--` first (since the string function is cheaper than the regex):

```
function validateAlphaNumericUnderscore($string) {
    if (false === strpos($string, '--')
        return 0 < preg_match('/^[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]$/i', $string);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Mark: Be sure to click the tick beside an answer to accept it. You can only accept one answer per question.

Answer (score 1):

[ircmaxell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168304/php-regular-expression-for-alphanumeric-and-hypen-input/4168395#4168395) uses a regex and a `strpos()` check, and is an answer I prefer, but here's how I did it with a single regex. Disclaimer: this has **vast room for improvement**:

```
function validate_alphanumeric_hyphenated($str) 
{
    /* 
     * Match either one or more alphanumeric characters, or a sequence with
     * a series of alphanumeric characters without consecutive, leading
     * or trailing hyphens.
     * 
     * Is probably unnecessarily long.
     */
    return preg_match("/^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|-(?!-))*[a-zA-Z0-9])$/", $str);
}
```

Comment: +1 or the single regex solution...  I have to admit, it took me a few minutes to figure out exactly HOW it worked (and I'm usually good with regex!), but it looks to be on the money to me!  Nice one!

Comment: @ircmaxell: Thanks! I happen to be practicing lookaround syntax with some of my regex answers, so mine can get unnecessarily long, as proven by meagar :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with two regexes:

```
if( !preg_match('/(?:^-|-$|-{2,})/',$str) && preg_match(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/',$str) ) {
     return true;
}
```