# Looking For a Specific Filter PHP

Tags: php, filter, validation

I'm trying to validate a the user's username. I want it to be able to have letters and numbers, no more than 30 characters.

Are there are built in PHP filters that would be able to accomplish this for me? Those manual regex things hurt my brain...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330693/validate-username-as-alphanumeric-with-underscores

Comment: Unfortunately regex is the best tool for the job you describe… Something like http://www.regexbuddy.com/ is a good tool to learn about them! And I'm going to go with `/^[a-z0-9]{1,30}$/i` as the best regex!

Comment: LOL ... all of the answers are exactly the same idea!

Comment: @JonahBishop and they're all deficient in one way or another. *\*sad face\**

Comment: @salathe I updated my solution to employ a few of the suggestions here. Is it still deficient in some way? If so, how?

Comment: @JonahBishop yours shares a similar issue that all of the others suffer from: it accepts a trailing newline character (not alphanumeric, and may be the 31st character). This is due to what `$` matches by default. A quick fix is to add the `D` pattern modifier, or the `\z` assertion in place of `$`.

Comment: @salathe Thanks for the information. I had no idea that $ matched against \n. I don't think that's the case in Perl, which begs the question as to why this is the default behavior (since this is a part of the "Perl compatible" regex package). I've updated my solution with that fix.

Comment: I actually take back my comment. Perl _does_ do the same thing. I had no idea, and I learned something new today. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are no built in filters.

You may want to consider [learning regular expressions](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php), they aren't *that* bad.

```
$valid = (strlen($username) <= 30 && preg_match("#^[a-z0-9A-Z]+$#", $username));
```

Comment: Consider using quantifiers in your regex instead of using `strlen()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are no filters for something this specific, however this works and has a simple regex:

```
function isValidUsername($username) {
    return (strlen($username) <= 30) && (preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+$/i", $username) == 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that should do it. I recommend spending some time learning how regular expressions work. They are one of the most powerful (and useful) tools in a programmer's toolbox.

**Update:** Using the delimiter suggestion from a comment above, and slightly simplifying my function:

**Update 2:** Added the /D pattern modifier to ensure that $ prevents a match against \n.

```
function isValidUsername($name)
{
  return preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/D", $name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into PHP to satisfy those requirements.  Here is the regex you'd need, though:

```
$valid = (bool)preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,30}$/', $username);
```

I know you didn't ask for design critique, but please think hard if usernames are really a necessity.  If not, think about using email addresses instead, as they're much more user-friendly, and you're likely going to ask the user for that info anyway.

Comment: so I would say... if ($_POST['username'] == $valid) { echo "the username is valid"       .. . .. . . and then it would become $username?

Comment: @Depetrify:  No, if the username you want to check is in `$_POST['username']`, you would use that instead of `$username` in the code above.  Then `$valid` would either be `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and you can go from there.