# Validate a string as alphanumeric with some special character

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have check this link [Validate username as alphanumeric with underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330693/validate-username-as-alphanumeric-with-underscores).

I want to  add more condition on string  checking

My conditions;

**Condition1:** `Alphanumeric including ! "#$%&'()*+,-./:;=?@^_~`

How can do this in php help

### Edit:

try with [melwil answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475030/2940291)

It show syntax error:

```
<?php

if (preg_match("//^[A-Za-z0-9_! "#$%&'()*+,\-.\\:\/;=?@^_]+$/", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Just add these special character in your character class.

Comment: I don't get the differences between condition 1 and condition 2.

Comment: @anubhava,please add an answer

Comment: why negative vote.. I cannot understand those people whose  down vote question with any reason

Comment: It will be similar to already posted answer. I didn't downvote but I think you should show your current regex and clarity on condition1 and condition2 as they both look same.

Comment: hey @anubhava ,please check update of question .. it show syntax issue.Can u please help me

Comment: You can use this regex: `'/^[A-Za-z0-9_! "#$%&\'()*+,.:\/;=?@^-]+$/'`

Comment: thanks .. it working ...

Comment: @AmitBera You just had to escape the quote. If you comment on the answer, they can see it and fix it :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add them:

```
preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_! \"#$%&'()*+,\-.\\:\/;=?@^_]+$/", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/sT9lG9/1

Anything marked is legal. Be aware this does match space as well. If that was a mistake, just remove the space.